# I need chapter numbers in a WordPress Loop

Tags: php, recursion, php-5.3, wordpress

I tried to solve something but struggling the whole morning.
I have my WordPress posts already in the state that they can have a parent post.
done by:

```
add_action('init', 'add_hierarchy_to_posts');
function add_hierarchy_to_posts() {
  add_post_type_support( 'post', 'page-attributes' );
  $obj = get_post_type_object( 'post' );
  $obj->hierarchical =true;
  remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
}
```

I need my post numerized in chapters so thats
1. Introduction
2. Subject is great
 2.1 why great
 2.2 why subject
  2.2.1 better
  2.2.2 worse
   2.2.2.1 in best case
3. End

The problem is now, how to count subchapters.
The function is here so far, and it produces at least
1.0
2.0
3.0
3.1
3.2

```
global $chapter,$subchapter,$subchapter1,$subchapter2,$depper;

function is_child_of($postID) { 
    global $post; 

    $ico=$post->post_parent;
    return $ico;
}


function find_out_chapter_number($id){

        global $chapter,$subchapter,$subchapter1,$subchapter2,$subchapter3,$depper;

        if(is_child_of($id)==0){
                $chapter++;
                $subchapter=0;
        }
        else if(is_child_of($id)==$depper){
                $subchapter++;
        }

        $depper=$id;
        $ico=is_child_of($id);
        //$id. " - ".$ico." - ".
        return $chapter.".".$subchapter.".".$subchapter1.".".$subchapter2;
        }
```

The $depper variable stores the post id before.
I need it deeper and I thought its maybe something with recursion but I don't know.

The function is called from the wordpress loop with

```
$kapitel = find_out_chapter_number(get_the_ID());
```

and echoed before the_title();

Comment: Can you show us a working link of this?

Comment: download here as wordpress plugin widget http://www62.zippyshare.com/v/38624584/file.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this plugin... this will help.

[Page List plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-list/)

if you still facing the same problem. please leave your comment. i will give you another solution.